# Please some Help me translate this

Tags: vocabulary, simplified-characters, mainland-china

I could not use Google translate because its an image.

Your help will be appreciated.[image]

Comment: It says that your FAMILY NAME is INCORRECT on your birth certificate, you need to update your birth certificate -- change a new one.

Answer (score 2):

无出生证明原件，声明书上姓氏有误，须更换新声明 - 张

No original birth certification document, surname in the clarification does not match, please submit a new clarification document - Zhang

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is as follow:

无出生证原件，声明书上<del>名</del>(Crossed Out)姓氏有误，需更换新声明。 张

Which translated to:

**There is no original copy of birth certificate, wrong <del>first name</del> last name on the declaration statement, change of new statement is needed.**

The 张 at the bottom right corner can be refer to:

One of the common Chinese last name - 张 - Zhāng

OR

Measure word which translated to **Piece** (eg. Piece of paper)

Comment: 姓氏 should be **last name**. Right?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, already edited.

Comment: 张 is probably a last name, used as a signature.

Answer (score 0):

No original birth certificate. The last name on the declaration is incorrect. New declaration is required

Comment: 张 is a last name